# How To: Check Frequency Weighting in a Term Document Matrix, in 'topicmodels'

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm attempting to do some topic modeling using the R package `topicmodels`

I've done my pre-processing using the 'tm' package, per these instructions [R text file and text mining...how to load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927367/r-text-file-and-text-mining-how-to-load-data).

However, when I go to run my correlated topic model (CTM) using `topicmodels` in R, I receive the following error

```
 "Error in CTM...DocumentTermMatrix needs to have a term frequency weighting.
```

I've triple checked the structure of my DocumentTermMatrix shows it does have a frequency weighting:

```
 A document-term matrix (26 documents, 413 terms)

 Non-/sparse entries: 4804/5934
 Sparsity           : 55%
 Maximal term length: 13 
 Weighting          : term frequency - inverse document frequency (normalized) (tf-idf)
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: My experience with this sort of question is that the questioners are often confusing TermDocumentMatrices with DocumentTermMatrices. Your question certainly suggests that confusion.

Comment: @Dwin Apologies, for the nomenclature flub, it is indeed a DocumentTermMatrix, NOT a TermDocumentMatrix.

Comment: The DTM in 'topicmodels' does not recognize a term frequency weighting that uses TF-IDF, the work around was to use normal term-frequency weighting instead of TF-IDF, not ideal, but previous Blei et al. (2003) suggest that using TF-IDF is not necessary for LDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the weighting parameter to be weightTf if you use the slam package before:

```
m=as.simple_triplet_matrix(mm);
dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(m,weighting =weightTf)
```