# Load documents(represented by sentences) from a single text file in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have file with multiple lines, each one representing a document for my scenario. I searched how to create a corpus from it and found about R tm package function `readPlain` but that will load the whole text file as one document. I also found the way to load documents at [R text file and text mining...how to load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927367/r-text-file-and-text-mining-how-to-load-data) but that specified the method which takes a folder path, and for each of the file in it, it creates a document.

How can I form different documents for each of the sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try readLines("/path/to/yourfile.txt")
Each line will be a different element in a text vector NLines long where Nlines is the number of lines in your document. 
Otherwise, see scan().
Both have a skip option if you need it, and an nlines option if you want to read it in chunks.

Comment: Also, you can skip the path part if you use setwd("/path/tofile/") to set your working directory to wherever the file is located. If you do that, all you need in readLines(file="",...) is the filename and extension.