# tidytext read files from folder

Tags: r, nlp, tidytext

I'm trying to read a folder of pdf files into a dataframe in R.  I'm able to read individual pdf files in using the `pdftools` library and `pdf_text(filepath)`.

Ideally, I could grab the author and title of a series of pdf's that are then pushed into a dataframe that has a column with these so that I can then use basic `tidytext` functions on the text.

For a single file right now, I can just use:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
txt <- pdf_text("filpath")
txt <- data_frame(txt)
txt %>%
     unnest_tokens(word, txt)
```

Here I have a dataframe with single words.  I'd like to get to a dataframe where I have articles unpacked including a title and author column.

Comment: You can get a list of files with `files <- list.files(".pdf")` and then read them in to a list with `txtList <- sapply(files,pdf_text)`.  Hopefully you can extract title/author from one of these too - although it is impossible to tell if you don't share an example of your data.

Comment: Andrew, thanks so much.  I was actually able to get the texts in as a list with your suggestion, but had a hard time getting this to be a dataframe where I could tidy up the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find all the PDFs within a working directory, you can use `list.files` with an argument:

```
all_pdfs <- list.files(pattern = ".pdf$")
```

The `all_pdfs` object will then be a character vector that contains all your filenames.

Then, you can set up a pipe to read in all the PDFs and unnest them using tidytext with a `map` function from purrr. You can use a `mutate()` within the `map()` to annotate each line with the filename, if you'd like.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

map_df(all_pdfs, ~ data_frame(txt = pdf_text(.x)) %>%
    mutate(filename = .x) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, txt))
```

You'll need to do some fancier work to get a title and author column, depending on where you have that information. Maybe with a regex on `txt` or `filename` before unnesting?

Comment: Excellent, works great to read all in as text.  How would I include the filename as a column?

Comment: Great!  I elaborated on this answer adding summary functions and stop words in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321956/1839959

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to add: `basename(.x)`. This will remove the full path information if you use the `full_names = TRUE` option in `list.files()` as I did.

```
df <- map_df(all_pdfs[3:5], ~ data_frame(txt = pdf_text(.x)) %>%
    mutate(filename = basename(.x)) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, txt))
```

Also if you experience any PDF parsing errors ..."Error in poppler_pdf_text(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : PDF parsing failure."..., you could try to create a `safe` version of the `pdf_text()` function with `safe_pdf_text <- purrr::safely(pdf_text)`. For more information on using the {purrr} package for this, see e.g. this blog by Bruno Rodrigues http://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2017-03-24-lesser_known_purrr/