# R, "tm" package - Error: Corpus Function not found

Tags: r, function, package, tm, corpus

I'm a rookie R/tm user and I have a dumb but annoying issue.

After downloading the 884 KB of tm package through this line [install.packages("tm")], setting my work directory and opening my file, I tried to use this function:

corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(mycorpus$title))

In response, R software writes: "Corpus function not found".

Do I have to install more packages or am I doing something wrong?

Before you ask, I've already checked here ([R text file and text mining...how to load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927367/r-text-file-and-text-mining-how-to-load-data)), but it wasn't helpful in this case.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Load your package first

```
library(tm)
```

Comment: It works, I knew it was something easy... Thank you and sorry for the silly question.